# python logarithm

Tags: python

i want to find out a log10 of an integer in python and i get an error like 
math domain error

my code is this 
w=math.log10(q*q1)/math.log10(2)

where q1,q2 are integers

yeah q1 is 0 sometimes

Comment: where is q2? why all of your questions are nonsense?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is q or q1 equal to zero or one of them negative?

Answer (score 11):

You can only compute the logarithm of a positive number. Trying to compute the logarithm for a negative number or zero will result in a "math domain error" in Python.

By the way: it looks like you're actually trying to compute a logarithm base 2. You can do this with `math.log`:

```
w=math.log(q*q1, 2)
```

The second, optional, parameter is the base. It defaults to e (ie: natural log).

Answer (score 1):

math.log10(0) is minus infinity.
See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm

Answer (score 1):

try to make sure the value whose log you are trying to find can never be 0. As log(0) tends to negative infinity, the function call will give you a math domain error. Correct that and I think you'll be fine.